# Good book for Monte Carlo methods in c++?

Tags: c++, physics, montecarlo

Can anybody recommend a good introduction book on Monte Carlo algorithms in c++? Preferably with applications to physics, and even more preferably, the kind of physics being quantum mechanics.

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably better off removing the C++ requirement - perhaps make it C or C++.

Comment: Monte carlo algorithms (and algorithms in general) are usually best expressed in language-agnostic pseudocode so that the implementer can easily translate them into his/her language of choce.

Comment: There's lots to know about doing numerics in general, and specifically in C++, but that's not really specific to Monte Carlo techniques.  One library to look at, because you'll probably end up using it a lot, is CGAL: http://www.cgal.org/

Comment: +1 for leading me to wiki a new way to waste time with a deck of cards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a look at Morten Hjorth-Jensen's [Lecture Notes on Computational Physics](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/fys/FYS3150/h10/undervisningsmateriale/Lecture%20Notes/lectures2010.pdf) (pdf file, 5.3 MB), University of Oslo (2009), chapters 8-11 (especially chapter 11, on Quantum Monte Carlo).

However, you should make sure you are not trying to learn too many things at the same time (Monte Carlo, C++, quantum mechanics). There are very good references (or introductory books) for each one of those topics separately.

Comment: Those lecture notes look great! And free is a good price. Good point about learning many things at once - I should know the QM by know, so it'll *only* be c++ and monte carlo ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[Numerical Recipes in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431085) (or [C++ now](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521750334)!).

Comment: Personally I think those books are awful. Keep in mind the copyright on the source code is rather restrictive. Here's a balanced view: http://www.astro.gla.ac.uk/users/norman/star/sc13/sc13.htx/N-a2b3c1.html.

Comment: Jason: I pretty much agree with that assessment.  NR is a starting point for academic uses.  I'm assuming OP is not writing commercial software.

Comment: No, it's not commercial, I'm writing an undergrad project in physics

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a book with a finance slant to it, my initial assessment of [Monte Carlo Frameworks: Building Customisable High-Performance C++ Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470060697) is very positive.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a book just on Monte Carlo methods or just about C++, but a good book about general computational physics that has a few chapters on Monte Carlo methods including quantum Monte Carlo is [Computational Physics](http://www.tn.tudelft.nl/tn/People/Staff/Thijssen/comphy.html) by J.M. Thijssen.

Also, one good package for some Monte Carlo simulations is the [ALPS Project](http://alps.comp-phys.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page). All of the codes are written in C++. The ALPS Project also has a program in it for Density Renormalization Group theory which is a great method mostly for 1D lattice simulations. These are more for simulations on lattices though and I don't know what sort of quantum simulations you are looking to do.

Comment: ... there's lots of info out there apparently!

Answer (score 1):

Look for Radford Neal's Markov Chain Monte Carlo lecture notes.

Answer (score 1):

Jerome Spanier and Ely M. Gelbard wrote a book many years ago called "Monte Carlo Principles and Neutron Transport Problems," which has been released for ~$12 in the last year or so.  Jun Liu wrote a good book several years ago, but it's more of a statistician approach to use MC and MCMC.  Lots of good material in there though with some advanced applications.  I have a paperback version that I picked up for ~$30.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look in to those.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using C# instead ?

I would recommend you the book of George Levy http://www.amazon.fr/Computational-Finance-Using-C/dp/0750669195. This book deals with financial mathematics and so with Monte-Carlo methods..